# Problem with build Gradle 7.2 , still writtencolud not find Gradle 6.1.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I just downloaded gradle6.1.1 to my android studio ,every time i build any project i get the following: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :capacitor-app
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File
  is there a way anyone can help me… or may be tell me where to save gradle-6.1.1.pom on my device.
  Thank you

Comment: After exactly a week of searching, I found a solution.
I tried everything they offered but nothing worked.
I'm surprised no one has solved such a problem.
So the solution was in my application. I needed to manually rewrite the node_modules @capacitor Gradle version from 6.1.1 to 7.1.2 (currently set) to all my configured modules.
I hope someone will help my solution in the future.

Answer (score 2):

build.gradle file must be like that

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file must be like that

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip